# C++ How to bind arguments to functions with same return type and store them all in one container

Tags: c++, components

### Intention and context

I have a class named `Component`. 
It looks somewhat like this (PSEUDO CODE):

```
template <class t>
class Component{
private:
    map<Entity, List<t>> attachedEntities;
public:
//Some other stuff like constructors, setters and getters etc.
     template<typename... Args>
     void addTo(const Entity &en, Args...args)
    {
        this->addTo(en,std::make_shared<t>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

    template < typename U, typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of<t, U>::value, U>::type* = nullptr >
    void addTo( const Entity &en,U* ptr)
    {
        this->addTo(en,shared_ptr<t>(ptr));
    }
    void addTo(const Entity &en,const std::shared_ptr<t> ptr)
    {
        /*
            Does the actual adding to the map
        */
    }
}
```

(For anyone wondering the Entity is the same as the Target from the previous version of this question. Entity made more sense on second thought)

**For educational purposes I am not willing to write wrappers for the passed variables.**

As you can see, the class Component has 3 addTo functions. Right now my system is a simple Component Entity system, where the Entity represents a UUID which is used as a key in maps. These maps, when brought into context with a single UUID can then "form" a complete Entity.

For example a entity might have a entry in

- StringComponent
- TextureComponent
- ModelComponent

and when a function iterates through all Models and looks for the fitting string and texture, it will render what we desire. For example the model that was associated with the Entity in the ModelComponent could be a Model of a Chest, the Texture a diffuse Texture for the Chest Model and the String could simply say what the player should see before interacting with it.

This already works great in my program! What I am struggling however, is making some sort of Template for a Object, that will then get instanced over and over again. For this example lets say I want to make a Entity that represents a `Bullet`

The bullet might have:

- A Model representing what it looks like
- A CollissionBox to detect when stuff collides with it
- A Sound that is played when it impacts
- Some sort of Tag (StringComponent) to make sure that the update Function updates it properly (so maybe it would have the tag "Bullet_big")

Again this works, however right now only by making the Enitity immune to being Deleted and just having the other bullets be Copies of that Entity. This is bad for the following reasons:

- It adds something to the game that can be interacted with but not be deleted. If I made it so it would be inacessable to everything but deletes, that would still add a overhead, because some sort replacement must be given when a get or set is called
- Its a unusuable item in every map it has. This can become a problem with larger programs where there are potentially hundreds of these "Templates" floating around
- If the Template gets deleted, either by oversight of the Developer or by a bug, the copies will most likely cause a crash or start acting wierd.

### What I am actually struggling with

**What I am looking to do now is to write a `Blueprint` class**

This class should simply be:

- A container that can be used to create new Entities that all have the same Components.
- Without being actually enlisted in any maps.
- Aaaand without having to manually case-check every Component name to identify which one to add (that would be dumb).

Here is what I was thinking about:

```
class Blueprint{
private:
    vector<function<???>> frozenAddFunctions; //Some way of storing all the functions with the init paramters but WITHOUT the entity specified;
public:
    template<t,typename... Args>
    void addTo(Component<t>, Args...args){
    //Somehow binding the approperate addTo overload to the arguments
    }
    void applyOnto(Entity &en){
        for(function f:this->frozenAddFunctions){
            f(en); //somehow invoke the addTo functions onto the Entity.
        }
    }
```

If this is impossible, please help me find a way of achieving this, whilst avoiding the negative points I listed.

Thanks in advance.

I hope this rendition was better.

Comment: What's the "Additional Info" for? Why don't you [edit] your question so that it's a whole, instead of separate iterations of edits pasted together? That said, can you reduce your problem to two functions or does that work? BTW: Each invocation's parameters can be stored in a tuple and a type that can hold values of multiple types is called a variant.

Comment: this really smells of an XY problem.  The compiler already offers this functionality in its function overload mechanisms.  Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Do you know how to create a lambda function and store it in a `std::function`? If that doesn't work, why not?

Comment: Why don't you just create a wrapper class that has all these addTo overloads and let the compiler figure out which overload to call?

Comment: Ok so I am gonna spend a bit of time answering all these comments and then try to write a example using pseudo code.
@MivVG I cant because the type that is passed is defined by a template parameter that is given to the class of the component that is being "addedTo". Giving the function itself such a paramter would solve the problem, however that would create a potential type-mismatch and I dont want to have some obscure error codes floating around like that (type mismatch is less obvious than no matching function call). I might be full of crap, tho that is just my guess

Comment: @UKMonkey Im not trying to reinvent overloading im trying to store functions which arent exactly the same in the same container.

Comment: @DDrmmr That might work, im gonna give it a shot in a bit

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I didnt edit it, that was all in the first rendition. I do agree that its a bad format. Im gonna redo it with more pseudo code.

Comment: @Jarod42 Unfortunately I rewrote it with more content, however I tried to be more specific and include a lot more examples and pseudo code. I hope this is better

Comment: [OT]: *"`shared_ptr<t>(ptr)`"*, I would get rid of overload which silently convert raw pointer in `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want:

```
class Blueprint
{
private:
    std::vector<std::function<void(Entity &)>> functions;
public:
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    void addTo(Component<T>& component, Args...args)
    {
        functions.emplace_back([=, &component](Entity& ent)
        {
            component.AddTo(ent, args...);
        });
    }

    void applyOnto(Entity &en)
    {
        for(const auto& f : functions){
            f(en);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I am getting a error when trying to use your class. blueprint.h|14|error: expected identifier before '=' token| (Referring to the line "functions.emplace_back"

And this one, it might be a follow up error.

|16|error: 'args' is not captured| (referring to the line "component.AddTo(ent, args...);"

Comment: typo fixed in capture: `[=, &compponent]`.

Comment: Thanks :) I temporarily fixed it myself by replacing the = with args..., however this silution seems a lot better ;) Works like a charm. The delete is bugged now for some reason but thats what I get for not doing UnitTests. Ill fix it. Thank you for your help :O